# nested <p:selectOneMenu does not update value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have two selectOneMenu one update the other, but the second one do not update its value, and still remains with the first value, despite in any code, this two  variables are equal so themselves.  Even the valueEventChangeListener returns the estados_eam value. Thanks guys, any help will be very appreciate. Best regards.

```
<h:outputText value="ESTADO:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="estados_eam" value="#{estadosMB.clave}"
                    style="width:200px;" required="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un estado" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{estadosMB.estadosMap}" />
                    <p:ajax listener="#{municipiosMB.handleEstadosChange}" update="municipios_eam"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message for="estados_eam" />

                <h:outputText value="MUNICIPIO:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="municipios_eam" valueChangeListener="#{municipiosMB.selectOneMenuListener}"
                    value="#{municipiosMB.idMunicipio}" label="Municipios"
                    converter="javax.faces.Integer" style="width:200px;" required="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un Municipio"
                        itemValue="#{null}" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{municipiosMB.municipiosMap}" />
                    <p:ajax listener="#{municipiosMB.handleMunicipioSelectedChange}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message for="municipios_eam" />
```

Bean code:

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "municipiosMB")
    @ViewScoped
    public class MunicipiosMB implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 112312323213445L;

        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MunicipiosMB.class);

        @ManagedProperty(value = "#{MunicipiosService}")
        private MunicipiosService municipioService;

        @ManagedProperty(value = "#{estadosMB}")
        private EstadosMB estadosMB;



        private Map<String, String> municipiosMap;
        private Municipio selectedMunicipio;
        private String clave;
        private Estados estado;
        private Integer id;
        private String nombre;
        private String siglas;
        private String estado_clave;
        private Municipio municipio;
        private Integer idMunicipio;

        public void updateMunicipio(Municipio municipio) {
            this.clave = municipio.getIdEstado().getClave();
            this.id = municipio.getId();
            this.nombre = municipio.getNombre();
            this.setMunicipio(municipio);
        }

        public Municipio getMunicipio() {
            return municipio;
        }

        public void setMunicipio(Municipio municipio) {
            this.municipio = municipio;
        }

        public String getClave() {
            return clave;
        }

        public void setClave(String clave) {
            this.clave = clave;
        }

        public Estados getEstado() {
            return estado;
        }

        public void setEstado(Estados estado) {
            this.estado = estado;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public String getSiglas() {
            return siglas;
        }

        public void setSiglas(String siglas) {
            this.siglas = siglas;
        }

        public Municipio getSelectedMunicipio() {
            return selectedMunicipio;
        }

        public void setSelectedMunicipio(Municipio selectedMunicipio) {
            this.selectedMunicipio = selectedMunicipio;
        }

        public MunicipiosService getMunicipioService() {
            return municipioService;
        }

        public void setMunicipioService(MunicipiosService municipioService) {
            this.municipioService = municipioService;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getMunicipiosMap() {

            return municipiosMap = municipioService.getMunicipiosByClaveEstado(estadosMB.getClave());
        }

        public void setMunicipiosMap(Map<String, String> municipiosMap) {
            this.municipiosMap = municipiosMap;
        }

        public EstadosMB getEstadosMB() {
            return estadosMB;
        }

        public void setEstadosMB(EstadosMB estadosMB) {
            this.estadosMB = estadosMB;
        }



        public Integer getIdMunicipio() {
            return idMunicipio;
        }

        public void setIdMunicipio(Integer idMunicipio) {
            this.idMunicipio = idMunicipio;
        }

        public void handleEstadosChange() {
            try {
                if (estadosMB.getClave() != null || !estadosMB.getClave().equals("77")) {
                    this.idMunicipio=0;
                    logger.info("  valor muncipio "+ this.idMunicipio);
                    logger.info("La clave seleccionada es "+estadosMB.getClave());
                    this.setMunicipiosMap(municipioService.getMunicipiosByClaveEstado(estadosMB.getClave()));
                    logger.info("Clave Estado Seleccionado:  " + estadosMB.getClave());
                    logger.info("Clave Municipio Seleccionado:  " + this.idMunicipio);
                } else {
                    this.idMunicipio=0;
                    this.setMunicipiosMap(new HashMap<String, String>());
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                logger.info("EstadosMB Null");
                this.setMunicipiosMap(new HashMap<String, String>());
            }
        }

        public void handleMunicipioSelectedChange() {
            logger.info("municipio seleccionado:::::: "+this.getIdMunicipio());
            logger.info("municipio seleccionado2:::::: "+this.getId());
        }

        public Municipio selectedMunicipio() {
            return municipioService.getMunicipiosById(this.getId());
        }

        public void selectOneMenuListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            //This will return you the newly selected
            //value as an object. You'll have to cast it.
            Object newValue = event.getNewValue(); 
            logger.info("valor nuevo"+ newValue.toString());
            //The rest of your processing logic goes here...
        }

    }

I don't have any idea, why it is happending here...My EstadosMB

@ManagedBean(name="estadosMB")
@ViewScoped
public class EstadosMB implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{EstadosService}")
    private EstadosService estadosService;

    private String clave = "";
    private Map<String,String> estadosMap;

    public EstadosService getEstadosService() {
        return estadosService;
    }

    public void setEstadosService(EstadosService estadosService) {
        this.estadosService = estadosService;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getEstadosMap() {
        return estadosMap = estadosService.getEstadosMap();
    }

    public void setEstadosMap(Map<String, String> estadosMap) {
        this.estadosMap = estadosMap;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Update the menu in the listener method in the bean by adding this line:

   ```
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("municipios_eam");
   ```
2. Use a p:remoteCommand to update the 2nd menu, so instead of:

   ```
   <p:ajax listener="#{municipiosMB.handleEstadosChange}" update="municipios_eam"/>
   ```

   use:

   ```
   //the remoteCommand should be placed before the first menu
   <p:remoteCommand name="updateMuncipios_eam" update="municipios_eam"/>

   <h:outputText value="ESTADO:" />
   //some more code
   <p:ajax listener="#{municipiosMB.handleEstadosChange}" oncomplete="updateMuncipios_eam()/>
   ```

Comment: I've tryed, those solutions but stills presents the same behavior.

Comment: The second menu municipios_eam it is updating its  list but the captured value it is not updating on selected item, value captured in this menu is the same at the estados_eam.  Thanks very much.

Comment: the service it returned the wrong value in the municipio_eam list.